# First order nonlinear ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms, nonlinear-system

In my exercise I am stuck in a problem given below:
$\ln\left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right) = x-y+1$
Although I could solve it if it was a linear equations. But ln() is a nightmare for me. Can anyone help me to learn this kind of problems?
Thank you.

Comment: Then remove it by taking the exponential of both sides ;).

Comment: By the way, here is a tutorial of typing math formulas on this site: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Transform it to exponential form
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{x-y+1}=e^x e^{-y+1}$$
and see it is separable.